# Element not fully aligned with bottom; Slightly lower than bottom edge

Tags: html, css, position

When using absolute positioning on an element within a div with a relative position rule, the element is slightly lower than the bottom of the parent div. Why does this happen? How would I solve this? I realize I can just mod the bottom value on .hoverAction, but that seems more like a workaround than an actual fix.

```js
function showFileUploadDialog()  {
    //do stuff
}
```

```css
#avatarContainer {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}

.hoverAction {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
 color: white;
 display: block;
 width: calc(100% - 12px);
 padding: 6px;
}

#avatar {
 width: 200px;
 height: 180px;
 background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
 border-radius: 1px;
 background-color: #eeeeee;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="avatarContainer">
 <a class="popup-link" href="{{ anime.poster }}"><img id="avatar" style="background-image: url('http://www.herdofsquirrels.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/squirrel-nut-cute-animal-nature-grass-1920x1280.jpg');" /></a>
 <a class="hoverAction" href="#" onclick="showFileUploadDialog(); return false;">Update Avatar</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pcwhmft6/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` top your `img`

```
#avatar {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pcwhmft6/2/

or set your image to `display: block` (Thanks @Justin Breiland for noticing)

Comment: Or set the image to display: block;

Comment: He has his image set to inline-block if you didn't notice.

Comment: @JustinBreiland Oh right. I didn't even notice that.